# Is there a better syntax for let*, when let* _ =?

Tags: ocaml, monads

For no other reason than it looks ugly and is hard to explain for non-OCaml programmers, is there an alternative to

```
let* _ = do_something in
```

?

There is of course `>>= fun() ->`, which does not look better.

Maybe

```
let (;*) = >>= fun () ->
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is better to write,

```
let* () = do_something in
...
```

To make it explicit that the return type is `unit`.

The is no provision for a monadic operation returning `unit` in the new [binding operator](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/bindingops.html) syntax, but there exist various ppx extensions, e.g., [ppx_monadic](https://bitbucket.org/camlspotter/ppx_monadic/src/default/) that provide the do-notation.

Finally, you can use sequencing operators, provided by your monadic library, for example, in Monads there is [sequence](https://binaryanalysisplatform.github.io/bap/api/master/monads/Monads/Std/Monad/module-type-S/index.html#val-sequence), so you can write,

```
sequence [
 do_one_thing;
 do_another_thing;
 and_so_on;
]
```